# How do i make my discord bot respond to a message with prefix?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

What I'm trying to do is set up a discord autoresponse bot that responds if someone says match prefix + respondobject like "!ping". I don't know why it doesn't come up with any response in the dispute. I've attached a picture of what it does. I can't figure out why it's not showing up with any responses in discord.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client({intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES"]});
const prefix = '!'

client.on('ready', () => {
let botStatus = [
  'up!h or up!help',
  `${client.users.cache.size} citizens!`,
  `${client.guilds.cache.size} servers!`
]

setInterval(function(){
  let status = botStatus[Math.floor(Math.random() * botStatus.length)]
  client.user.setActivity(status, {type: 'WATCHING'})
}, 15000);
  console.log(client.user.username);
});

client.on('message', message => {
  if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return
  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/)
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase()

  const responseObject = {
  "ping": ` Latency is ${msg.createdTimestamp - message.createdTimestamp}ms. API Latency is ${Math.round(client.ws.ping)}ms`
};

  if (responseObject[message.content]) {
    message.channel.send('Loading data...').then (async (msg) =>{
    msg.delete()
    message.channel.send(responseObject[message.content]);
  }).catch(err => console.log(err.message))
  }
});

client.login(process.env.token);
```

Comment: If `message.content` is `"!ping"` and `responseObject` has the property `ping` then `responseObject[message.content]` is always `undefined`. Did you mean to use `responseObject[command]`?

Comment: are you running discord.js V13? If so, please change the `message` event, to `messageCreate`

Comment: Thanks @LeeLenalee, i use responseObject[command] and it works normally.

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is that you're trying to check `message.content` against `'ping'`, but require a prefix. Your `message.content` will always have a prefix, so you could try `if (responseObject[message.content.slice(prefix.length)])`.

Other alternatives would be to add the prefix to the object (`"!ping": "Latency is..."`)

Or, create a variable that tracks the command used.

```js
let cmd = message.content.toLowerCase().slice(prefix.length).split(/\s+/gm)[0]
// then use it to check the object
if (responseObject[cmd]) {}
```